# VBA IIF statement in Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to do a multi condtion IIF statment and I keep getting error 3075 (missing operator). Please see my syntax

```
IIf(Count(Factor1.Factor) = 1, Temp.Value*Sum(Factor1.Factor), IIf(Count(Factor1.Factor) = 2 And Temp.Vendor =YYYY , Temp.Value*Max(Factor1.Factor),Null) As [Value]
```

I'm not sure if it is missing parenthesis or qoutes around text field. I tried adding both but it still errors. If there's a better way using switch or fixing this would be a great help.

Comment: I believe you're missing a closing bracket before `As [Value]`. Also, any text inputs will also need to be enclosed in single quotes e.g. `'YYYY'`.

Comment: Missing closing parentheses as well text delimiters. You have tagged VBA but there is no valid VBA posted. Is this expression in a textbox?

Comment: The answer is **DON'T**.  Use standard if then else statements.  IIf is really provided to provide a nice shortcut when the programmer wants to select between two constants.  You should never ever put calculations or method calls in an IIF statement because both of the clauses in an IIf statement are evaluated before choosing which result to use based on the condition.  This means that IIf statements are very prone to unanticipated side effects.

Comment: @freeflow How are you suggesting to have the standard if then else statements inside an SQL query?

Comment: When the OP states it is an SQL Query, which he doesn't in his post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this in a SQL statement, hence the "as [value]". If Then Else would be impossible to use in SQL.

To see where you've made a syntax error, copy the text into a text editor and break the lines like this, to see where the missing brackets/commas are:

```
IIf( Count(Factor1.Factor) = 1
   , Temp.Value*Sum(Factor1.Factor)
   , IIf(Count(Factor1.Factor) = 2 And Temp.Vendor =YYYY 
        , Temp.Value*Max(Factor1.Factor)
        ,Null
        ) 
   <<here>>
   As [Value]
```

The next error would be a complaint over the YYYY.